# seekbar customization: progress and secondaryProgress property not stretch pictures default

Tags: android, coding-style, seekbar

I customize my seekbar like below:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/progress_seekbar" android:background="@drawable/play_progress_bg"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginBottom="-9dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/playwidget" android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_seekbar_style"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_progress" />
```

in my progress_seekbar_style.xml file, I specified it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/play_progress_01" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/play_progress_02" />
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/play_progress_03"/>
</layer-list>
```

I want to use this seekbar customization for different screen size; but when it display on the large screen like 600x1024, the seekbar will repeat the picture which I set in "@android:id/background,secondaryProgress/progress " , not stretch my pictures. and I need it automatically stretch my picture to fill parent width. that is what I want, but it just repeat the picture.

can you help? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using nine-patch images. Nine-patch is stretched if you use it for background (even for progress or seek bar).

For testing just rename your image from img.png to img.9.png